# Linux: "Found duplicate PV XXXXYYYYY: user /dev/sdb1 not /dev/sda1"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, hard-drive

I'm trying to resize my virtual hard disk, so I've cloned it, and right now I have two disks in my virtual machine.

I'm trying now to boot off the old virtual disk and then resize the new hard disk's partitions, but when I do pvresize complains that there duplicate physical volumes (PV) with the same ID (presumably because I cloned my disk).

What do I do?

Can i just change the ID of one of the physical volumes?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered trying pvchange -u on the new physical volume to give it a new UUID?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of pvchange. I have since scrapped the whole thing and re-installed Ubuntu on a big virtual hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just disconnect the old volume since you have already cloned it?

Comment: I'm booting off the old volume to make changes to the new volume (unmounted)

Comment: Boot off a live CD instead. Or make the changes in single-user mode, if you can. LVM doesn't cope with having duplicate PV UUIDs.

Comment: It would probably be easier and safer to simply boot off a livecd and do the resize with the livecd.

Comment: which live cd would you recommend? are you sure its not simpler just to change the pv id?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this and I would do it om a disk that I didn't care about but the [LVM FAQ](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recovermetadata.html) says "pvcreate only overwrites the lvm metadata areas on disk and doesn't touch the data areas (the logical volumes). ". So you might be able to get away with doing a pvremove followed by a pvcreate although as I say I would do it with a disc of data I didn't care about first